# Accessing Event Arguments in Action scriptblock of Register-ObjectEvent cmdlet

Tags: events, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to access the Event arguments in the -Action scriptblock of the Register-ObjectEvent cmdlet? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The `EventArgs` object is available inside the Action script block as a magical variable called `$Event`. This is what `get-help Register-ObjectEvent -detail` has to say:

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent):

> The value of the Action parameter can
>   include the $Event, $EventSubscriber,
>   $Sender, $SourceEventArgs, and
>   $SourceArgs automatic variables, which
>   provide information about the event to
>   the Action script block. For more
>   information, see
>   about_Automatic_Variables.